# jQuery keyup event not working after partial view reload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

On my Index View, I have the below relevant jQuery code that executes when a user either hits Enter or clicks the Search Icon to trigger a Search:

```
<div class="homeContent">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_homeIndexContent.cshtml")
</div>

@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set focus on load to the Search box.
    document.getElementById("Search").focus();

    $("#Search").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode==13){
            alert("Index.cshtml - Enter Pressed - Method inside Document.Reader().");
            searchAssets();
        }
    });

// Called when user clicks the magnifying glass icon next to the Searchbox.
    function searchAssets() {
        alert("Index.cshtml - searchAssets() called.");
        var searchValue = document.getElementById("Search").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("search", "Home")',
            data: { searchCriteria: document.getElementById("Search").value },
            success: function (resp) {
                $(".homeContent").html(resp);
                document.getElementById("Search").value = searchValue;
                document.getElementById("Search").focus();
                var rows = $('.grid-table tbody tr').length;
                $('#rowCount').html(rows);
                setVerifyBtnClass();
            }
        });
}
```

**HomeController**:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchCriteria)
        { 
            fillPagingIntervalList();
            var SearchResults = db.TABLE.ToList().Where(m.Status.STATUS_DESCRIPTION != null && m.Status.STATUS_DESCRIPTION.ToString().ToUpper() == searchCriteria.ToUpper() || // Other search Code
            // Return the "refreshed" partial view without reloading entire page.
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_homeIndexContent.cshtml", SearchResults);

        }
```

Everything appears to work fine on the first search, but partial view has reloaded I can no longer perform a new Search by clicking the ENTER key. 
I can still trigger a new search via the Search Icon being clicked, but why can I no longer use the Enter Key?

If I am just reloading the Partial View, I would think my jQuery inside the Document.Ready() should still be accessible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but partial view has reloaded I can no longer perform a new Search by clicking the ENTER key

You should use event delegation **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** since the element with id `Search` will be added dynamically after the reload, simple `keyup` event can't deal with fresh DOM :

```
$("body").on("keyup", "#Search", function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        alert("Index.cshtml - Enter Pressed - Method inside Document.Reader().");
        searchAssets();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This actually does the job @AnalyticLunatic wants.. this happens because `$("#Search").keyup(function(event)` is ran when document is ready and at that point, the change it makes wont no longer be the same object and `jQuery` will not know where to look because the code is not being executed again... I say this just to explain why this happens and why the shown code works

Answer (score 0):

When you are running `$("#Search").keyup(...);` you are attaching to any element currently on the page that has the `id` of `Search`. When you load a new partial, the old element that is listening for the `keyup` event is destroyed, and a new copy is made. This new element is not listening for `keyup`

Your choices are clear: run the same `keyup` listening code right after loading in the partial, or do the Better thing and use event delegation:

`$('body').on('keyup', '#Search', function() { ... });`

Now, the `body` tag is listening for any `keyup` events that happen inside of all children that match the `'#Search'` selector.